# Curvature for a curve with constant angle between position vector and tangent vector

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a plane Frenet curve such that the angle $\theta$ between $\alpha(s)$ and its tangent vector $e_1(s)$ is constant. Show that either $\kappa = 0$ or

$$\kappa(s) = \frac{1}{\cot \theta + c}$$

where $c$ is a constant.

*Hint:* It holds that

$$\big< \alpha, e_1 \big> = |\alpha| \cdot \cos \theta$$

as well as

$$\big< \alpha, e_2 \big> = \pm |\alpha| \cdot \sin \theta$$

where $\dot{e}_1(s) = \kappa(s) e_2(s)$. Differentiate the first equation ...

--- ${}$ --- ${}$ --- ${}$ --- ${}$ --- ${}$ --- ${}$ ---

I tried solving this by using the hint given but I always ended up with a term containing $| \alpha |$, which I cannot get rid of. I already considered that maybe $| \alpha|$ is the constant $c$ and I therefore do not even have to get rid of it. But then again I cannot assume $|\alpha|$ to be constant a-priori although It may be (as for e.g. $\theta = \pi/2$).

I humbly ask for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is just wrong. The only planar curves with constant curvature are circles, and only when the circle is centered at the origin will the angle between $\alpha$ and $e_1$ be constant (as you surmised, $\pi/2$). So $\cot\theta$ must be $0$ and $\kappa=1/c$.

I tried solving this the way I usually approach all such problems. I wrote the arclength parametrized curve $\alpha = \lambda  e_1 + \mu e_2$ for some functions $\lambda$ and $\mu$, differentiated and applied the Frenet equations. The hypothesis in the problem tells us that $\lambda = \pm\cot\theta \mu$ (or $\mu=0$, which leads to $\kappa=0$). Assuming $\kappa\ne 0$, we get the equations
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\kappa\cot\theta&\mu + &\mu' &= 0 \\
-\kappa&\mu + \cot\theta&\mu' &= 1,
\end{alignat*}
and so  $\mu = \dfrac{-1}{\kappa\csc^2\theta}=\dfrac{-\sin^2\theta}{\kappa}$ and $\mu' = \dfrac{\kappa\cot\theta}{\kappa\csc^2\theta} = \cos\theta\sin\theta$. This tells us that $\mu(s)=(\cos\theta\sin\theta)s + c$, and so
$$\kappa(s) = \frac{-\sin^2\theta}{\mu(s)} = \frac{-\sin^2\theta}{(\cos\theta\sin\theta) s + c},$$
very different from the statement of the problem. By the way, since $\kappa>0$, we should probably have opted for the negative sign choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

At first I arrived at your conclusion as well, i.e. that only circles satisfy the conditions (note here, that a straight line is a circle with curvature radius infinity and therefore is covered by this problem as well [case: $\kappa = 0$]).

However, I found this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166995/if-0-theta-frac-pi2-then-gamma-is-a-logarithmic-spiral
I don't really understand some of the steps there, but I guess he comes to the conclusion that logarithmic spirals are also a possibility.

Comment: Yes, then what they told you to prove is impossible, as it had $\kappa$ constant. The logarithmic spiral does follow from what I have. I'll edit.

Comment: I received an update from my exercise class. There was indeed an error in the problem statement. The curvature should actually be

$$ \kappa(s) = \frac{1}{\cot \theta \cdot s + c}$$

Which is essentially the same as your result, so hats off to your solution.

However, I dont understand your solution fully. You said you differentiated the equation $\alpha = \lambda e_1 + \mu e_2$. But what is the derivative of $e_2$ and can one assume that it really exists?

Comment: Frenet equations!

Comment: Ok, I finally understood your solution in its entirety. Thank you for your kind help!